# Sculpt mode and number of polygons

Tags: sculpting

When you use sculpt mode to create a model, is it more or less efficient than creating your standard box then extruding etc. to achieve the desired effect.  The reason I ask is that the sculpt mode is so much more intuitive for me than the other method probably because I am so new and don't know the tricks to round ends etc. more easily than how I do it now.

However, is the resulting sculp creation loaded with extra polygons because I am using an easier method to create the object and if so, is there any way to optimize the object to reduce the number of polygons yet maintain the level of detail.

I have searched on this subject but to be honest the couple of instances where I found discussions were just a bit beyond what I understand at this stage.  I would greatly appreciate any guidance.

Natarthos